# How to find trending hashtags based on use case in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

At first, that is my schema file

```
create_table "events", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "title"
  t.text "description"
  t.string "location"
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  t.index ["user_id"], name: "index_events_on_user_id"
end

create_table "events_hash_tags", id: false, force: :cascade do |t|
  t.integer "event_id"
  t.integer "hash_tag_id"
  t.index ["event_id"], name: "index_events_hash_tags_on_event_id"
  t.index ["hash_tag_id"], name: "index_events_hash_tags_on_hash_tag_id"
end

create_table "hash_tags", force: :cascade do |t|
  t.string "name"
  t.datetime "created_at", null: false
  t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
end
```

`hashtags` creating successfully in `hash_tags` table and creating the association with `events_hash_tags`.

I want to know how to find the trending `hashtags` based on use cases like if 10 hashtags on `hash_tags` table then how to find which `hashtag` used in most events if one `hashtag` used in 10 events and that is maximum then how to find that programmatically.

My question is how to find 5 trending `hashtags` which used maximum time of events.

Perdon if I did not explain well.

Thanks

Comment: You want to scan table _events_hash_tags_ and see which `hash_tag_id`s top the list i.e. occur most of the time.

Comment: Thanks, I have not any model for ***events_hash_tags***, what can I do now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another answer from @PatMellon is partially right the reason is @questionnaire said in the comment, below the answer which is the `name` column is unique and it associated with `events_hash_tags`.

I think you need to follow the [**`has_many :through`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association) Association and [**`counter_cache`**](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs-to) for counting association.

And then

```
@trendings = HashTag.limit(5).order(events_hash_tags_count: :desc)
```

I think it will help

Answer (score 1):

`HashTag.all.group('name').count.sort_by {|_key, value| value}.reverse.to_h` would give a sorted count of all the hash tags entered in your db. If you add a where query you can limit your search to the day, week, or whatever. If you ran a query like this every hour it would list the most used, or trending, hashtags for that hour.

Comment: Yes you are right, but the `name` column is unique it associated with ***events_hash_tags***